# Why those ElasticSearch queries doesn't return the same results?

Tags: elasticsearch

This request returns object:

```
{
"query" : {
    "match" : {
        "docId" : "56696636"
    }
}
}
```

But this returns nothing:

```
{
"query" : 
{
    "bool" : 
    {
        "must" : 
            {
                "ids" : 
                {
                    "type" : "docId",
                    "values" : [ "56696636" ]
                }
            }
    }
}
}
```

I'm new in ElasticSearch, but in my opinion both of them should return the same. Why they don't?

(I'm using elasticsearch 0.90.5)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I missed this part of documentation : ids query can be used only to search by ID